# Parse HTTP access log in order to get all request with 429 respond within one sec

Tags: text-processing, awk, logs, nginx

Typical access.log file from nginx

```
000.00.000.001 - - [28/Jun/2021:06:37:02 +0100] "POST /abc/cba/ HTTP/1.1" 429 1157 "data..."
000.00.000.002 - - [28/Jun/2021:06:37:02 +0100] "POST /abc/cba/ HTTP/1.1" 200 741 "-" "data..."
000.00.000.001 - - [28/Jun/2021:06:37:02 +0100] "POST /abc/cba/ HTTP/1.1" 429 741 "-" "data..."
000.00.000.001 - - [28/Jun/2021:06:37:02 +0100] "POST /abc/cba/ HTTP/1.1" 429 741 "-" "data..."
000.00.000.001 - - [28/Jun/2021:06:37:02 +0100] "POST /abc/cba/ HTTP/1.1" 429 741 "-" "data..."
000.00.000.001 - - [28/Jun/2021:06:37:02 +0100] "POST /abc/cba/ HTTP/1.1" 429 741 "-" "data..."
000.00.000.003 - - [28/Jun/2021:06:37:03 +0100] "POST /abc/cba/ HTTP/1.1" 429 741 "-" "data..."
000.00.000.003 - - [28/Jun/2021:06:37:03 +0100] "POST /abc/cba/ HTTP/1.1" 429 741 "-" "data..."
000.00.000.003 - - [28/Jun/2021:06:37:03 +0100] "POST /abc/cba/ HTTP/1.1" 429 741 "-" "data..."
000.00.000.003 - - [28/Jun/2021:06:37:03 +0100] "POST /abc/cba/ HTTP/1.1" 429 741 "-" "data..."
000.00.000.003 - - [28/Jun/2021:06:37:03 +0100] "POST /abc/cba/ HTTP/1.1" 429 741 "-" "data..."
000.00.000.004 - - [28/Jun/2021:06:37:03 +0100] "POST /abc/cba/ HTTP/1.1" 429 741 "-" "data..."
000.00.000.004 - - [28/Jun/2021:06:37:03 +0100] "POST /abc/cba/ HTTP/1.1" 429 741 "-" "data..."
000.00.000.004 - - [28/Jun/2021:06:37:03 +0100] "POST /abc/cba/ HTTP/1.1" 429 741 "-" "data..."
```

The question is how could I get all IP addresses from the log file that had response code 429 and are made within one sec any time. I am trying to find a solution with awk but no success yet if somebody could give a hint.
The output for a given example would be:

```
28/Jun/2021:06:37:02:
000.00.000.001
28/Jun/2021:06:37:03:
000.00.000.003
```

1. only IP that made more or equal of 5 request
2. have response status 429
3. group by seconds if there is something show in response any time not a specific second

Comment: Please edit your question and include what you have already tried, and how that failed

Comment: Can you supply an example of input and output?

Comment: what do you mean by "within one second"?  do you mean "within one **specific** second and ignore all the rest"?  or do you mean "group by timestamp with a different output line for each second"?

Comment: If you require reliability and prompt response, [write an nginx module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187314/how-to-write-a-nginx-module) instead of trying to hack something together that's misusing the state-based data store of a log file as an event-driven communication channel.  If you want something that kinda works, most of the time, maybe, stick with the log-file-parsing hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk -F'[[ ]+' '$9==429{print $4, $1}' file | uniq -c | awk '$1>4{print $2 ":\n" $3}'
28/Jun/2021:06:37:02:
000.00.000.001
28/Jun/2021:06:37:03:
000.00.000.003
```

If the content within the first set of quotes (e.g. `"POST /abc/cba/ HTTP/1.1"`) isn't always 3 space-separated strings as in your sample input then just tweak it to this:

```
$ awk -F'[[ ]+' '{sub(/"[^"]*"/,"")} $6==429{print $4, $1}' file | uniq -c | awk '$1>4{print $2 ":\n" $3}'
28/Jun/2021:06:37:02:
000.00.000.001
28/Jun/2021:06:37:03:
000.00.000.003
```

If you prefer an awk-only solution for some reason:

```
$ awk -F'[[ ]+' '$9==429{cnt[$4":\n"$1]++} END{for (key in cnt) if (cnt[key]>4) print key}' file
28/Jun/2021:06:37:02:
000.00.000.001
28/Jun/2021:06:37:03:
000.00.000.003
```

All of the above scripts will work just using mandatory POSIX tools in any shell on every Unix box.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I really needed, one thing to mention only 3'td example return the case when between 5 sequential IP is placed another one within one second.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know what that means, though, sorry. If your posted sample input/output isn't adequate to demonstrate your requirements then edit your question to fix it.

Comment: Actually - maybe I do know what you mean and if so then changing `uniq -c` to `sort | uniq -c` would solve the problem. Please do still fix the example in your question though.